# ¿Como usar desde el codigo la imagen que importo a visual studio?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion en `WPF (C# y XAML)`.

He usado estas instrucciones para importar una imagen a `Visual Studio`: que luego quiero mostrar en una parte de la applicacion. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474366/visual-studio-adding-an-image-to-project

Ahora, lo que quiero lograr es manipular esta imagen desde el codigo, en lugar de refecenciarla desde el `XAML` puro, como aparece en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como lo hago?

Tal vez sea muy obvia o simple mi pregunta, pero no encuantro por ningun lugar como hacer esto.

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: no te entiendo.. que queres hacer con la imagen? la imagen esta en esa ruta. para el codigo es lo mismo que para el XAML...

Comment: Quieres cargar la imagen con codigo y no en el designer? Explicate un poco mejor.

Comment: Agradezco mucho su tiempo. Finalmente encontré la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de importar las imagenes:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474366/visual-studio-adding-an-image-to-project

```
        digital_watch = new Image();
        digital_watch_image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"images\digital_watch.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        digital_watch.Source = digital_watch_image;
        Grid.Children.Add(digital_watch);
```

Asi es como manipulas la imagen.